# HTML text input allows only alphanumeric input and some other characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html

I need to validate a text input with the following characters: `[\w\s\.\,\-\à\è\é\ì\ò\ù]`

My HTML code is:

```
<input type="text" id="customer_name" placeholder="Your name..." maxlength=100 />
```

and the javascript code (using jquery) for validation is:

```
$('#customer_name').on('keypress', function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    // 13: enter, 8: backspace, 46: del, 37: left arrow, 39: right arrow
    if(keyCode == 13 || keyCode == 8 || keyCode == 46 || keyCode == 37 || keyCode == 39) {
        return;
    }

    // Validate input
    else if (String.fromCharCode(keyCode).match(/[\w\s\.\,\-\à\è\é\ì\ò\ù]/)) {
        return;
    }

    else e.preventDefault();
});
```

This code works well if I type characters, but it fails if I try to copy and paste other special characters (e.g., `@#`).

I also tried to replace the original regex with `[0-9A-Za-z_\s\.\,\-\à\è\é\ì\ò\ù]`, but nothing changed. However, if I delete lowercase characters (i.e., `[0-9A-Z_\s\.\,\-\à\è\é\ì\ò\ù]`), then it works even with copy-paste, thus denying  characters like `@#` (but obviously I cannot enter lowercase characters).

What is wrong? Is there any other better method to validate this kind of input?ù

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f_ficarola/e24zbxz0/4/)

**EDIT1**

I understood the reason. As I copy-paste a string, the combination `CTRL-v` is recognized as keycode 118, i.e. **v** character:

[image]

Comment: Change `keypress` to `input`

Comment: BTW, it is not necessary to escape each and every char in the character class. `/[\w\s.,àèéìòù-]/` will do. If `-` is at the end of the character class, it does not have to be escaped. You may add more chars before the `-`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: changed, but now typing does not work, too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: thanks for the tip. Anyway, "dot" must be escaped in your string! :)

Comment: @f_ficarola No, it should not. A dot inside a character class matches a literal dot.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: oh yes, you're right! ;) I forgot I was inside [].

Comment: Why don't you use html input `pattern`? And why are you checking with every key pressed and not at submit?

Comment: @Fallenhero: I cannot use a form. And the main goal is avoiding to enter characters not allowed. Then, I will check on submit as well.

Comment: @DragandDrop: here you are: https://jsfiddle.net/e24zbxz0/